# findviewwithtag

Tags: android, layout, view

```
DragCar dCar = new DragCar();
dCar.poolId = car.pool_id;
dCar.postion=car.position;
dCar.railCarNumber = car.railcar_number;
dCar.status = car.status;
dCar.track = car.trackId;
dCar.type = car.type;
dCar.yard = car.yardId;
View view = new View(context);
view.setTag(dCar);
parent.addView(view);
View view = parent.findViewWithTag(dCar);
```

view after findviewwithtag(dCar) returns null Value. DragCar is a custom class object used to know about the car.

Comment: where does `view` come from initially, with just the code posted here you should get null pointer when you call `view.addTag(dcar);`

Comment: i have edited the code. is there any way to override the findViewWithTag() Method.